# Sort records by time inserted

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can I query data in the order it was created?

I don't have a ***date-created*** field in this table.

Comment: Does the table have a Primary Key?

Comment: Unless you have an `identity` field, to the best of my knowledge you can't

Comment: do you you have an identity column? with auto increment?

Comment: Yes, but it is in fact an identity field...

Comment: Identity fields also can't be relied on, guys....

Comment: I don't mind if its not 100% accurate... but at least a idea.

Comment: If it's both a PK and an identity you can probably use it but there's no guarantees.

Comment: Sorry my mistake... the primary key is a GUID

Comment: so I'm out of lock with this one.. I heard that guid's are based partly on the date, that's why I had hope I can get it.

Comment: GUIDs are based on a lot of things depending on the algorithm.  In SS 2008 there is a `NEWSEQUENTIALID` which is a sequential GUID.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't have a field storing the time of insertion, or any other meta-data regarding the order of insertion, **there is no reliable way to get this information.**

You could maybe depend on a clustered index key, but these are not guaranteed.  Neither are `IDENTITY` fields or other auto-generated fields.

To clarify, an `IDENTITY` field does auto-increment, but...

- You can insert explicit values with `IDENTITY_INSERT`
- You can reseed and start reusing values
- There is no built-in enforcement of uniqueness for an identity field

If the ID field is  your PK, you can probably use that to get a rough idea:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY IdField ASC
```

Per your comment, the field is a `GUID`.  In that case, there is no way to return any sort of reliable order since `GUID`s are inherently random and non-sequential.

Comment: Sorry my mistake... the primary key is a GUID. can I still get the sort?

Comment: Nope, `GUID` is a random non-sequential value.  There's no order to it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NEWSEQUENTIALID().

Comment: its too late now... also its a 2005 server.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this questions because I was facing the same issue and here is the solution that worked for me.

Alter the table and add an `IDENTITY(1,1)` column and that identity column will be auto-populated for existing rows when you add it. It will be in the order in which records were inserted.

It worked in my case but not sure if it works in all cases or not.